# Reducing size of dSYM files for symbolication

Tags: ios, crashlytics, dwarf, symbolicatecrash, dsym

We are looking for ways to reduce the size of dSYM files from Apple platforms. We need dSYM files just for symbolicating stack traces of crashes and in Crashlytics blog I read [this](http://fabric.io/blog/2016/09/08/how-crashlytics-symbolicates-1000-crashes-every-second/):

> These mappings actually hold much more than needed just for
> symbolication, presenting some opportunities for optimization. They
> have everything required for a generalized symbolic debugger to step
> through and inspect your program, which may be a huge amount of
> information. On iOS, we have seen dSYMs greater than 1GB in size! This
> is a real opportunity for optimization, and we take advantage of this
> in two ways. First, we extract just the mapping info we need into a
> lightweight, platform-agnostic format. This results in a typical
> space-saving of 20x when compared to an iOS dSYM.

Reducing size by 20x sounds very good but I found little information on how this can be done. Do I need to learn details of Mach-O DWARF to achieve this or some of the command line tools can do this? I also wonder if the stripped version can be used direcly afterwards for symbolicating.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crashlytics converts dSYMs to cSYMs and uses these cSYMs for symbolication. This conversion happens on client's Macs. You might want to look into the final size of this cSYM file that is actually uploaded to crashlytics.

Comment: Thanks Chintan. I guess this cSYM is a custom format of theirs, right? Searching for it didn't return much. We want to do it ourselves.

Comment: Yes, cSYM is a custom format, it is deleted once the upload-symbols script is finishes it's run